# Swift delegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates, viewcontroller

I have a stepper in my ViewController that controls the value of a variable in my UIView.  When I reset the variables to 0 in my UIView, I also want the stepper and label to reset, but they won't.  I tried using a delegate, but am getting an error.  Thanks in advance!

ViewController:

```
protocol CircleViewDelegate: class {
    func updateStepper(view: CircleView)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CircleViewDelegate {

var colors = CircleView()

@IBOutlet weak var circleView1: CircleView!
@IBOutlet weak var blueStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var greenStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var redStepper: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var redValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var greenValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var blueValue: UILabel!

var circleViewDelegate: CircleView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    circleViewDelegate!.delegate = self
}

func updateStepper(view: CircleView) {
    redStepper.value=0.0;
    greenStepper.value=0.0;
    blueStepper.value=0.0;
}

@IBAction func stepperChange(sender: UIStepper) {
    circleView1.redd1 = Int(redStepper.value);
    redValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
}

@IBAction func stepperChange1(sender: UIStepper) {
    circleView1.greenn1 = Int(greenStepper.value);
    greenValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
}

@IBAction func stepperChange2(sender: UIStepper) {
    circleView1.bluee1 = Int(blueStepper.value);
    blueValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
}
```

}

UIView:

```
class CircleView: UIView {    
    var redd1 = 0
    var greenn1 = 0
    var bluee1 = 0

    weak var delegate: CircleViewDelegate?

    func updateStepper() {
        delegate?.updateStepper(self)
    }

    func game() {
        if(redd1==Int(red1) && greenn1==Int(green1) && bluee1==Int(blue1)) {
            redd1 = 0;
            green1 = 0;
            blue1 = 0;
            updateStepper()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: on this line: circleViewDelegate!.delegate = self , i get the error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: You don't need `circleViewDelegate` - you want to say `circleView1.delegate=self`

Comment: thanks i fixed it, but I'm still having the problem in my question

Comment: Set a breakpoint.  Is your delegate method being called?

Comment: yes I have my functions print and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    circleView1.delegate = self
}

func updateStepper(view: CircleView) {
    redStepper.value = 0.0
    greenStepper.value = 0.0
    blueStepper.value = 0.0

    stepperChange(redStepper)
    stepperChange(greenStepper)
    stepperChange(blueStepper)
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to call the `IBAction` method you were probably expecting to be called. This will update both the label and the `CircleView`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the delegate like this `circleViewDelegate!.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad` try `circleView1.delegate = self`

Comment: it fixed the error but i still have the same problem in my question